# Decode UTF-8 encoded string in swift

Tags: swift, utf-8

I have a variable `x` type of String containing a `UTF-8` encoded text.
This text doesn't need encoding because it already been encoded, so it became weird

```swift
print(x)

// >>> æç©ºè¦³å¯ã«æé©ãªã­ã±ã¼ã·ã§ã³
```

I want to decode this text from `UTF-8` to normal text like I can do on this page [>>link](https://www.browserling.com/tools/utf8-decode)

I wasn't able to find a solution for doing this in swift. Is it even possible? When yes, how please?

The text should look like this

```
星空観察に最適なロケーション
```

Comment: I've copy and pasted your text "// >>> æç©ºè¦³å¯ã«æé©ãªã­ã±ã¼ã·ã§ã³" into the link you show, and nothing happens.

Comment: I know, it is somehow changed by stackoverflow when I saved this post

Comment: How variable x receives value?

Answer (score 0):

> I have a variable x type of String containing a UTF-8 encoded text

Strings in Swift work differently. It is up to the `String` class to choose how it internally stores the characters.

The methods and properties of the `String` class are either encoding agnostic (i.e. they work the same no matter how it is internally stored), or they are very explicit about the encoding.

If you have data encoded in UTF-8, you should treat it as a byte array or `Data` instance and then pass it to the `String` class as such:

```
let bytes = // UInt8 array with UTF-8 encoded text
let string1 = String(bytes: bytes, encoding: .utf8)

let data = ... // some Data instance with UTF-8 encoded text
let string2 = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
```

Even though both strings are created with UTF-8 encoded data, the `String` class can convert it into a different internal format.

You don't show how you create the string in the first place. It is possibly where something goes wrong.